# How to split each element of a string array and form a new array?

Tags: java, arrays

Suppose I have a string array

```
NumText[]={“00111”， “01110”， “10110”}，
```

now I want a new array

```
BinaryText[]={"0","0","1","1","1"......"1","1","0"},
```

which means I have to split each element of the array NumText[], and combine all the bits I get into a new array. What I can figure out is that I define a string array for each element, like

```
Binary0=NumText[0].split("");
Binary1=NumText[1].split("");
Binary2=NumText[2].split("");
```

After that I have to remove the leading zero of each BinaryX, and concatenate them together, which is really a bad idea. Any better ways? I appreciate your help.

Comment: You can try using Arrays.copyOfRange()

Comment: Why dont you convert these values to integer before you do the first split operation so that you dont have to remove the leading zeroes.

Comment: Use a nested loop. The outer should loop on NumText, and the inner should loop on the characters of each string.

Comment: @Eyal Schneider Nice solution, I've tried it.

Answer (score 1):

use two loops the outer for the whole array and the inner for the string at each index:

```
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i < numText.length; i++){
   for( int j = 0; j < numText[i].length(); j++){
        temp.append(numText[i].charAt(j));
   }

}

char[] newArray = temp.toCharArray();
```

Comment: It seems that the requested output is a string array, not a char array.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too...

```
String[] numText = { "00111", "01110", "10110" };
char[] binaryText = (Arrays.toString(numText).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replaceAll("[, ]", "")).toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you removing the Zeros but here is my answer

```
String [] s = {"01 110"," 10010","01010"};
        ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i =0 ; i<s.length;i++){
            s[i]=s[i].replaceAll("[0\\s]", "");
                for(int j = 0 ; j<s[i].length();j++){
                    list.add(Character.toString(s[i].charAt(j)));
                }
        }
        System.out.println(list.toString());
```

Comment: ArrayList used, that's cool. And what I wanted to move are not those 0s, but the 0 generated by 'split'. Since I split on an empty string, I guess the resulted array would have a leading 0. That is the case with my last effort to split an user input string letter by letter and store them in an array. Anyway, I won't have such problems with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
String numText[] = { "00111", "01110", "10110" };
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < numText.length; i++) {
    numText[i] = numText[i].replaceAll("^[0]*", ""); //Remove leading zeros
    for (int j = 0; j < numText[i].length(); j++) {
        sb.append(numText[i].charAt(j));
    }
}
String[] output = sb.toString().split("");
```